# Meteor MongoDB - cant insert _id with _id from API call

Tags: mongodb, meteor, twitch

I am trying to call the TwitchAPI and insert some of the returned data into MongoDB. However, every time I get this error: `Error: Meteor requires document _id fields to be non-empty strings or ObjectIDs`.

The Twitch API response for a single stream/channel looks like this:

```
{
  "streams": [
    {
      "_id": 11220687552,
      "game": "League of Legends",
      "viewers": 11661,
      "created_at": "2014-09-30T01:10:36Z",
      "_links": {
        "self": "http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/mushisgosu"
      },
      "preview": {
        "small": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mushisgosu-80x50.jpg",
        "medium": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mushisgosu-320x200.jpg",
        "large": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mushisgosu-640x400.jpg",
        "template": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mushisgosu-{width}x{height}.jpg"
      },
      "channel": {
        "_links": {
          "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu",
          "follows": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/follows",
          "commercial": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/commercial",
          "stream_key": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/stream_key",
          "chat": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/mushisgosu",
          "features": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/features",
          "subscriptions": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/subscriptions",
          "editors": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/editors",
          "videos": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/videos",
          "teams": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mushisgosu/teams"
        },
        "background": null,
        "banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/mushisgosu-channel_header_image-c5c08cce281b7be3-640x125.jpeg",
        "display_name": "MushIsGosu",
        "game": "League of Legends",
        "logo": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/mushisgosu-profile_image-b1c8bb5fd700025e-300x300.png",
        "mature": false,
        "status": "CLG hi im Gosu - Challenger AD - Smurfing Master!",
        "partner": true,
        "url": "http://www.twitch.tv/mushisgosu",
        "video_banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/mushisgosu-channel_offline_image-7e3401b20cb5d739-640x360.png",
        "_id": 41939266,
        "name": "mushisgosu",
        "created_at": "2013-03-31T21:12:14Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-09-30T03:08:55Z",
        "abuse_reported": null,
        "delay": 60,
        "followers": 318914,
        "profile_banner": null,
        "profile_banner_background_color": null,
        "views": 25963780,
        "language": "en-us"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_total": 8477,
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=1&offset=0",
    "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=1&offset=1",
    "featured": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured",
    "summary": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/summary",
    "followed": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed"
  }
}
```

The part of my server method that tries to insert the data

```
            Meteor.call('getStreams', function(err, res) {
                var data = res.data.streams;
                console.log(data);
                data.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log(item._id);
                    Streams.insert({
                        _id: item._id,
                        title: item.channel.status,
                        author: item.channel.display_name,
                        url: item.url
                    });
                });
            });
```

getStreams simple defines the url to call and sets some variable. As you can see I am console logging the expected `_id` so I know it is returning a valid string but I am still getting the error. Currently, when I make the call I return 100 streams at a time and iterate through them to save the 4 fields above. Ideally, I would like to save each stream object as its own entry in the DB but all my attempts to do that have resulted in the same error and I also read somewhere that the version on "miniMongo" bundled with Meteor does not support inserting an array of objects in bulk...I also have read that miniMong does not support `Collection.save()` so sadly I think it will be more later to update the contents of each `_id` with the latest API call info since I cant just use `.save` to update and insert in the same statement.

I am not sure if it has any impact but I did try setting `autoIndexId` to `false` when creating the collection and it doesn't seem to matter:

`Streams = new Meteor.Collection('streams', {autoIndexId: false});`

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: did you eventually make your website public? :D dunno what it is but I would love to check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the twitch `_id` is NOT a `String`, it appears to be a `Number` (I can tell by the output of your JSON : the number is not surrounded by quotes).

What I'd do is let Meteor generate its own internal Mongo IDs and store the twitch `_id` as a separate property instead.

```
Streams.insert({
  twitchId: item._id,
  title: item.channel.status,
  author: item.channel.display_name,
  url: item.url
});
```

You will have to retrieve the streams by `twitchId` instead of `_id`, but it's hardly a problem, right ?

Comment: For the time being since miniMongo already doesn't support `.save()` I will need to write a function to check if the twitchId exist and update it but in the future if `.save()` gets supported would there be another method to match twitch's `_id` with mongos? I tried to `toString()` the `_id` before saving but now its throwing a duplicate key error. Might just need to do a lil more trouble shooting but is this the right approach?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why exact mapping between twitch `_id` and your collection `_id` is a concern ? If it really is, have you considered using `upsert` as a `save` workaround ?

Comment: The only reason I had in mind was being able to do `Streams.insert(item)` to save the entirety of each stream object without calling out individual properties explicitly. There is probably a better solution but I am new to MongoDB and still trying to wrap my mind around the DB structure since I am used to normal sql style DBs.

Comment: I understand. Here is a possible workaround that works by "renaming" the `_id` property to `twitchId` in the original item : `item.twitchId=item._id;delete item._id;`